# Can't get Edge to Return a Promise in my WebExtension

Tags: javascript, promise, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to create a new tab using `browser.tabs.create()` from my `background.js` WebExtension as shown here:

```
createTab: function () {
    var newTab = browser.tabs.create({ url: someUrl });
    newTab.then(onCreated, onError);
}
```

**The new tab creates in the browser**, but when the last line is reached, an error is thrown:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference

The Locals window shows `newTab` is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought that `.create()` would immediately return a `Promise`. I know `create()` is an asynchronous function - but my calling function doesn't need to by async, does it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps Edge is broken - the code looks fine, especially since you say the new tab is actually created

Comment: Can you show us `browser.tabs.create` body?

Comment: Sadly, no.  `browser.tabs.create` isn't my method, it's part of the API defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reading the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis) (who knew?) and came across this little gem:

[image]

Seems pretty definitive; now I just need an example of using callbacks for it instead...

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Baker already mentioned, Microsoft Edge extension APIs sadly don't support promises.

So you could refer to [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onCreated) on how to use callbacks:

```
browser.windows.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log("New tab: " + tab.id);
});
```

---

Or even better: Provide the callback directly as second parameter to the `create` function:

```
var newTab = browser.tabs.create({ url: someUrl }, (tab) => {
  console.log("New window: " + window.id);
});
```

See the chrome docs (seems to apply for Edge, too): https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

Please note: You can achieve the same, if you're aiming for a new window (instead of a new tab) with `windows.create(object createData, function callback)`