# Vue.js error in IE11

Tags: vue.js, syntax-error

I am running Vue.js and have a component running on my page. The component works just fine in Chrome, Firefox etc, but in IE11 it is throwing the following error

```
Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError: Invalid character
    "Unhandled promise rejection"
    {
        [functions]: ,
        __proto__: { },
        description: "Invalid character",
        message: "Invalid character",
        name: "SyntaxError",
        number: -2146827274,
        stack: "SyntaxError: Invalid character
            at Anonymous function (http://mydomain/js/app.js:6:21534)
            at a (http://mydomain/js/app.js:7:5220)
            at Anonymous function (http://mydomain/js/app.js:7:5344)
            at c (http://mydomain/js/app.js:1:22805)"
    }
```

This isn't telling me much and searching google has not helped. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you opened up the IE11 dev tools and tried to trace when the exception occurs?

Comment: How does the component look like? Does it have backticks in the source code?

Comment: There are no back ticks in the component. And that error is the only thing that is output to the IE console

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that [IE doesn't support promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556792/127888).  Any JS code that relies on using them, like

```
axios.get('some/url/')
        .then(response => (this.dataThing = response.data));
```

... is going to fail.  You can use polyfills to translate this into something that IE11 understands, but I am unclear on how to implement them.